# How do I enable the PPTP addition dialogue when using a regular user in Debian Wheezie under Gnome Unity?

Tags: unity, networking, gnome, vpn, openvpn

I just installed openvpn, pptp and vpnc. Under the user I am using, I am unable to create a PPTP connection as the dialogue is grayed out. Under the root user login, I can with no problems, however I really cannot use that. What do I need to do to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the steps at http://jeffhoogland.blogspot.se/2012/05/howto-give-network-manager-sufficient.html and this resolved my issue.